# Java concat an split byte Array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an very very simple Server Client Connection.

I want to send an `byte[]` from one to the other. This Array should be generated from two other Arrays.
And then the Receiver must be able to get both Arrays from the single Array.

So, my idea was to take one Array, add an 0 or 1 Block and then add the second Array, send this and separate them.
Can someone show me an example how to encode and decode this? (Or an other approach?) - Only JDK Classes allowed.

Comment: can you use a 'split sequence' between client and server (i.e. a byte sequence that both will interpret as 'this is the array splitter')?

Comment: add a 0 or a 1 is very bad idea, except if you are absolutely sure that your arrays will not contain one of those values.

Comment: In a byte array any index can only be 0 or 1. So a placed index value with 0 or 1 is equals any other index! You need to implement a protocoll to transfer meta data like array length and counts etc.

Comment: If the array isn't that big, just put the length of the first table as the first value

Comment: Why, is it downrated? What have I forgot to tell you? @francesco, I don´t understand what you mean. @ others Oh your are right, didn´t thought about that, I will try to put the length in the first index.    Would it be possible if I put an Block between the Two, which is the Hash of the first Byte[]? (and yes, I guess it would be inefficient....)

Answer (score 0):

You should first send the length of the array, then you need to decode the length in the receiving side, and read the "length" next bytes into your array or other place, then read next length of array, read that array an so on.

It is up to you how would you send the length, it could be just ascii number characters terminated by ";" like "2002202;". Thew ASCII method will give you also easy way to add other messages to this protocol, for example non number ones.
Of course you need to implement this over TCP/IP

Comment: I got an Interface and an "protocol" what I have to use. So, I am not allowed to send the length. Would it be possible and sufficient to write the number of Bytes in the first Array into the first Index ?

Comment: Could you post what the proctocol is?

Comment: There is also a possibility to make a new connection each time you wish to send an array, and send one array per connection, but it is unefficient way. You can however distinguish then the end and start of transsmission, using just part of TCP/IP protocol conenction/disconnecion mechanisms.